# Cron job doesn't send mail

Tags: php, cron, phpmailer

My cron job is run but no email is sent.

```
/usr/bin/php -f /home/user/public_html/test/cron/checklist.php task=client
```

result = OK

```
<?php
//get parameter from URL 
$argv = $_SERVER['argv'];
$task = explode("=", $argv[1]);
?>
```

result = OK

Complication start here !

```
if(!$mail->Send()) { 
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo.'<br>';
} else {
    echo "Message sent!<br>";
}
```

It says "Message sent!" but no email is sent!
When I run it from a web page as a test, it works and sends mail

I use phpmailer to send.

Comment: Check your mail server logs.

Comment: The `mail` command will execute without error (usually) however if not using SMTP mail, your sent messages are likely getting either ISP-blocked or spam-filtered. Have recipients checked their spam folders(s)? http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm

Comment: Thank for your answer...                                                                                                                       I checked it and no problem write into logs

Comment: @Brolosse you may also want to check that any PHP file included (via `include` or `require`) might not be properly loading during crontab execution. When the cron runs, maybe try tailing the apache log for any php errors. Lastly, the `task=client` you might want to view accepted answer from as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858114/how-can-i-run-a-cron-job-with-arguments-and-pass-results-to-a-log

Answer (score 0):

Try `/usr/bin/php -f /home/user/public_html/test/cron/checklist.php client`

Also, in your PHP code, differentiate between web server handling and command-line handling.  Here's an example:

```
if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {
    echo "this is command line";
    $task = $argv[1];
} else {
    echo "run from a web server";
    $argv = $_SERVER['argv']; 
    $task = explode("=", $argv[1]);
}
echo "\n task =";
echo $task;
```

Comment: Of course be sure to check that argv has the necessary element quantity, with `isset` along with try and catch if you're not already doing so.